# How do I do dependency injection in a python's pyramid view callable?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, pyramid

Suppose I have a class

```
from pyramid.request import Request
from pyramid.view import view_config

def includeme(config):
    config.add_route('items', '/v1/items'

class MyView():
    def __init__(self, item: Item = None, booksvc: BookService = None, magazinesvc: MagazineService = None):
        self.booksvc = booksvc or BookService(self.)
        self.magazinesvc = magazine or MagazineService()
        self.item = item or Item(booksvc)

    @view_config(route_name='items', request_method='GET')
    def get_items(self):
        foo = self.item.bar()
        # do some more stuff
        return foo
```

How do I inject all of the dependencies (item, booksvc, and magazinesvc) to the view?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you'll need to define a custom view mapper which is the resource that is responsible for invoking a view. I'm unaware of any view mappers that come out of the box that will do this for you so I can only point you at the docs to write one yourself.

https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#using-a-view-mapper